# ¿Se confundía pestaña con párpado en el pasado?

Tags: etimología, historia, español-medieval, cuerpo-humano, español-medio

En textos antiguos he encontrado varios casos en los que se utiliza la palabra pestaña en una forma que no parece tener  sentido, pero que sí que lo tendría si en vez de "pestaña" dijera "párpado". Por ejemplo:

> " ... cerrado el ojo con la pulpa del dedo sobre la pestaña ..."
> Anónimo, *Traducción del Tratado de cirugía de Guido de Cauliaco* (1493)

En otros textos de la misma época aparecen con su significado habitual. Por ejemplo:

> Ojos grandes, fermosos, pintados, relusçientes,
> et de luengas pestañas bien claras e reyentes ...
> Arcipreste de Hita, *Libro de buen amor*

lo que me hace sospechar que antaño algunos autores confudieran estos términos. Así pues, ¿se confundía pestaña con párpado en el pasado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A juzgar por su uso en los textos mostrados, la respuesta a la pregunta principal tiene que ser “sí”. *A priori* no resulta extraño que se confundan párpado y pestaña, ya que son conceptual y anatómicamente muy próximos.

El Diccionario de Autoridades no indica realmente *palpebra* como origen etimológico de “pestaña”, sino que aporta solamente una traducción latina, como hace en (casi) todas las palabras españolas que define. En el caso de “párpado” sí se indica explícitamente que la palabra “es del latino *palpebra*”.

Una cosa curiosa y que podría haber influido en el uso literario de “pestaña” y “párpado” como sinónimos es que en latín clásico *[palpebra](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=palpebra)* significaba “párpado” pero su plural fue utilizado con el significado de “pestañas” por Plinio. Otro término, *cilium*, que también se usaba como “párpado”, terminó evolucionando (en su forma plural, *cilia*) en el español “ceja”.